# What’s the right way to use PonyOrm with FastApi?

Tags: python-asyncio, fastapi, ponyorm

For a personal project I am using PonyOrm with FastApi ; is there a classy way to keep a db_session through the whole async lifecycle call of an endpoint ?

The documentation of PonyOrm talks about using the decorator and yield; but it didn't work for me so after looking on other Github projects, I found this workaround which is working fine.

But I don't really know what's happening behind the scenes and why the documentation of Pony isn't accurate about the async topic.

```
def _enter_session():
    session = db_session(sql_debug=True)
    Request.pony_session = session
    session.__enter__()


def _exit_session():
    session = getattr(Request, 'pony_session', None)
    if session is not None:
        session.__exit__()


@app.middleware("http")
async def add_pony(request: Request, call_next):
    _enter_session()
    response = await call_next(request)
    _exit_session()
    return response
```

and then in a dependency for example :

```
async def current_user(
        username: str = Depends(current_user_from_token)) -> User:

    with Request.pony_session:
        # db actions
```

and in an endpoint call :

```
@router.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(
        request: Request,
        user_agent: Optional[str] = Header(None),
        form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):

    status: bool = authenticate_user(
        form_data.username,
        form_data.password,
        request.client.host,
        user_agent)


@db_session
def authenticate_user(
        username: str,
        password: str,
        client_ip: str = 'Undefined',
        client_app: str = 'Undefined'):
    user: User = User.get(email=username)
```

If you guys have a better way or a good explanation, I would love to hear about it :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't follow the patterns laid out in the documentation for other orms? IE, just using a plain dependency? See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/

Comment: the reason is this : https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/891#issuecomment-612831548 and https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/494

Comment: There's nothing in there that I can see stopping you from using a normal dependency

Answer (score 3):

I'm a kinda PonyORM developer and FastAPI user.

The problem with the async and Pony is that Pony uses transactions which in our understanding are atomic. Also we use thread local cache that can be used in another session if context will switch to another coroutine.
I agree that we should add information about it in documentation.

To be sure everything will be okay you should use `db_session` as the context manager and be sure that you don't have async calls inside this block of code.

If your endpoints are not asynchronous you can also use `db_session` decorator for them.

In Pony we agree that using `ContextVar` instead of `Local` should help with some cases.

The answer in one sentence is: **Use little shortliving sessions and don't interrupt them with async.**

Comment: Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: just one more question, do you find my approach good ? I am still getting random HTTP 500 like : 

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 475, in __exit__
    assert local.db_session is db_session
AssertionError

Comment: Is your approach changed after my answer? If yes - how?

Comment: Hi again. No, nothing changed.

Comment: So your problem here is `db_session` decorators that uses `async` inside. You need to replace it with `db_session` context manager

Comment: well not really. I changed my code to this : async starlette middleware that adds popy session to request -> then all my FastApi endpoints are sync and their dependencies too. But the session ends just after the first dependency call :(

Comment: Im not suggesting to use dependecies for pony db session. Just use context manager where you need it

Answer (score -1):

Try using a standard fastapi dependency:

```
from fastapi import Depends

async def get_pony():
    with db_session(sql_debug=True) as session:
        yield session


async def current_user(
    username: str = Depends(current_user_from_token),
    pony_session = Depends(get_pony)) -> User:

    with pony_session:
        # db actions
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :) this code didn't work for me, I think I will stick with the sync operations and keep db_session within the middleware :)